# How to set a JMS poller with activemq in mule

Tags: jms, mule

I have two separate messages being published to a staging.queue. I want the JMS consumer of the staging queue to wait 10 seconds before consumer all the messages from the staging.queue. I have the following strategy:

```
<jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" username="admin" password="admin" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ">
    <service-overrides transactedMessageReceiver="com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jms.TransactedPollingJmsMessageReceiver" />
</jms:activemq-connector>
<flow name="integration-consumer-client2" doc:name="integration-consumer-client2"> 
    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="client2.publish" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS"> 
    </jms:inbound-endpoint>
    <logger message="Consumes Client 2 = #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <logger message="Client 2 Correlation = #[message.correlationId] and Correlation sequence = #[message.correlationSequence]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="waiting.queue" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS"/>
</flow>
<flow name="integration-consumer-client" doc:name="integration-consumer-client">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint doc:name="JMS" connector-ref="Active_MQ" queue="client1.publish">
    </jms:inbound-endpoint>
    <logger message="Consumes Client 1 = #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <logger message="Client Correlation = #[message.correlationId] and Correlation sequence = #[message.correlationSequence]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="waiting.queue" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS"/>    
</flow>
<flow name="integration-Flow3" doc:name="integration-Flow3">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="staging.queue" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS">
     <properties>
        <spring:entry key="pollingFrequency" value="10000" />
    </properties>
    </jms:inbound-endpoint>
    <logger message="after poller = #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

but the consumer doesn't wait 10 seconds. it consumes the messages immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by following way :-

- Make **integration-Flow3** as a sub flow
- Use **flow-ref** to call the subflow **integration-Flow3** after **jms:outbound-endpoint** of both the flow :- **integration-consumer-client2** and **integration-consumer-client**
- Now in the beginning of  subflow **integration-Flow3**  remove JMS inbound endpoint and use a **Groovy Script** where you can define sleep(Your time)
- Then after  **Groovy Script** use **Mule Module Requester** component to call the JMS inbound endpoint ..

**Mule Module Requester** is the component that can able to call any inbound endpoint in the middle of the flow ..

You can found details of **Mule Module Requester** here https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-module-requester  and  http://blogs.mulesoft.org/introducing-the-mule-requester-module/

Just use it to call JMS inbound endpoint with q**ueue="staging.queue"** ..

Since you will be using GroovyScript before **Mule Module Requester** .. Groovy script will take care of holding the timer .. (You need to set sleep() method inside your Groovy Script ) .. That's all